# How can I migrate my JUnit4 testcase using JMockit mocked paramters to JUnit5?

Tags: java, junit5, jmockit

```
    @Test
    public void testPerformDeployment(@Mocked DockerClient d, @Mocked BuildImageCmd b,
            @Mocked BuildImageResultCallback c, @Mocked c1 createContainerCmd,
            @Mocked CreateContainerResponse cr) {
            // Test code here
    }
```

Passing parameters to a Junit5 test method throws an erro. what are my best options for receiving mocked objects inside the test method. I am using JMockIt 1.49.

Comment: "_Since JUnit 5 test methods do not accept parameters..._" – mistaken premise. JUnit 5 is perfectly capable of injecting test-method arguments but it needs to know how to resolve said arguments. This is done via a `ParameterResolver` extension.  You could write one yourself but you should probably see if JMockit provides an extension (or even composed annotation) first. For example, Mockito has the `MockitoExtension` class. I suppose another option is parameterized tests.

Comment: question edited to eliminate the mistaken premise. Looking for further info on parameter resolution mechanism.

Comment: For further information on how to resolve parameters with JUnit Jupiter, take a look at the [official docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection) or [this sample](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-parameters).